# Disable video in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have an html page with an embed video from vimeo(using fancybox).
I would like to popup sign up form that disable the player, which means that you have to sign up in order to watch the video.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place an image( pretending to be the video ) inside `iframe` with a click listener. When user click at the image your script should show sign up form. If sign up is successful replace the image inside `iframe` by video.